# Removing character from php string variable

Tags: php

I have a variable in PHP like `Logo™`. How do I remove the character `™`, if it's present?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it seems like you're getting data from an outside source, perhaps it might be better to filter out all characters you aren't expecting. What this will include will vary depending on what the variable is for. For example, if you're expecting it to be a single simple word, you could remove anything which isn't a letter.

```
$str = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z]/", "", $str);
```

Just be careful to think about what is and isn't allowed. The above code would remove accented characters, for example.

Answer (score 3):

`$str = str_replace(chr(153), '', 'Logo™');`

Comment: http://php.net/str_replace Replace all occurrences of the search string with the replacement string, in this example char with ascii-code 153 (™) will be replace to empty ('').

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = 'Logo™';
$str = substr_replace('™', '', $str); // Logo
```